# Get current week in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have been searching the web for the proper postgreSQL syntax for current_week. I searched through the link attached but could not get anything fruition out of it [Date/Time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html). My task is to get Sunday as the start of the week.

I tried same as current_date but it failed:

```
select current_week
```

There has to be a current week syntax for postgreSQL.

Comment: update the question to reflect that you want the week to start on Sunday?..

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[knowing that](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) for `extract('dow' from`

> The day of the week as Sunday (0) to Saturday (6)

and

> By definition, ISO weeks start on Mondays

You can workaround by substracting one day:

```
select date_trunc('week', current_date) - interval '1 day' as current_week
  current_week
------------------------
 2016-12-18 00:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

Here is sample:

```
t=# with d as (select generate_series('2016-12-11','2016-12-28','1 day'::interval) t)
select date_trunc('week', d.t)::date  - interval '1 day' as current_week, extract('dow' from d.t), d.t from d
;
    current_week     | date_part |           t
---------------------+-----------+------------------------
 2016-12-04 00:00:00 |         0 | 2016-12-11 00:00:00+00
 2016-12-11 00:00:00 |         1 | 2016-12-12 00:00:00+00
 2016-12-11 00:00:00 |         2 | 2016-12-13 00:00:00+00
 2016-12-11 00:00:00 |         3 | 2016-12-14 00:00:00+00
 2016-12-11 00:00:00 |         4 | 2016-12-15 00:00:00+00
 2016-12-11 00:00:00 |         5 | 2016-12-16 00:00:00+00
 2016-12-11 00:00:00 |         6 | 2016-12-17 00:00:00+00
 2016-12-11 00:00:00 |         0 | 2016-12-18 00:00:00+00
 2016-12-18 00:00:00 |         1 | 2016-12-19 00:00:00+00
 2016-12-18 00:00:00 |         2 | 2016-12-20 00:00:00+00
 2016-12-18 00:00:00 |         3 | 2016-12-21 00:00:00+00
 2016-12-18 00:00:00 |         4 | 2016-12-22 00:00:00+00
 2016-12-18 00:00:00 |         5 | 2016-12-23 00:00:00+00
 2016-12-18 00:00:00 |         6 | 2016-12-24 00:00:00+00
 2016-12-18 00:00:00 |         0 | 2016-12-25 00:00:00+00
 2016-12-25 00:00:00 |         1 | 2016-12-26 00:00:00+00
 2016-12-25 00:00:00 |         2 | 2016-12-27 00:00:00+00
 2016-12-25 00:00:00 |         3 | 2016-12-28 00:00:00+00
(18 rows)

Time: 0.483 ms
```

Comment: Thanks Vao, is there another alternative of getting this done. This indeed is a lengthy process just to get Sunday as the start of the week.

Comment: well - I just rephrased your `select date_trunc('week', current_date - 1) as current_week` to `select date_trunc('week', current_date) - interval '1 day' as current_week`

Answer (score 5):

One method would be `date_trunc()`:

```
select date_trunc('week', current_date) as current_week
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this shows Dec 19th as the current week. Is there anyway I can have to show Sunday, Dec 18th as the current week since the week starts on a Sunday.

Comment: @PythonLearner You can always subtract a day off it if you want it to be a Sunday.

Comment: select date_trunc('week', current_date - 1) as current_week .......
this still shows Dec 19th.

Comment: that's funny - `select extract('dow' from now())` shows day 2 and weeks start with day 0 so it starts with 18th

Comment: ` select extract('dow' from '2016-12-18'::date);` gives 0 => 18 is start of week - right?..

Comment: `extract(isodow from ...)` is in sync with `date_trunc('week', ...)` -- `extract(dow from ...)` is the legacy behavior.

Comment: I guess @PythonLearner wants "week as dow" while week in fact behaves like "isoweek" if it would exist